# Unable to start Vdebug

Tags: plugin-vim-plug

I am unable to start Vdebug. I am using Vim-Plug to handle my plugins, `:PlugStatus` on a PHP file gives a status of `OK`. However, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>, Vdebug is not started.

Does anyone has any idea what is going wrong? I also tried to change the mappings, but this had no effect.

I am using xfce4-terminal, and here is [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/rbnvrw/.dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)

```
" vim:fdm=marker:foldlevel=0
" Vim settings for Ruben Verweij
" Use Vim mode {{{
set nocompatible
" }}}
" Set encoding and file formats {{{
set encoding=utf-8 nobomb
scriptencoding utf-8
set fileformats=unix,mac,dos
set fileformat=unix
" }}}
" Use Plug for plugin management {{{
if empty(glob("~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim"))
    execute '!curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim https://raw.github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim'
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
" }}}
" Backup and undo settings {{{
if has("vms")
    set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
    set backup        " keep a backup file (restore to previous version)
    set backupdir=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
    set backupskip=/tmp/*,/private/tmp/*
    set directory=~/.vim-tmp,~/.tmp,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
    set writebackup
    set undofile      " keep an undo file (undo changes after closing)
    set undolevels=500
    set undoreload=500
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
" }}}
" Langnoremap setting {{{
if has('langmap') && exists('+langnoremap')
    " Prevent that the langmap option applies to characters that result from a
    " mapping.  If unset (default), this may break plugins (but it's backward
    " compatible).
    set langnoremap
endif
" }}}
" Basic shortcuts (leader) {{{
" Leader key
let mapleader=","
let maplocalleader=",,"
" Ever notice a slight lag after typing the leader key + command? This lowers
" the timeout.
set timeoutlen=500
" }}}
" Movement commands {{{
" move vertically by visual line
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
" }}}
" Insert mode misc settings {{{
" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" }}}
" Autoformat options {{{
set formatoptions=
set formatoptions+=c                  " Auto-wrap comments using textwidth
set formatoptions+=r                  " Continue comments by default
set formatoptions-=o                  " do not continue comment using o or O
set formatoptions+=q                  " continue comments with gq
set formatoptions+=n                  " Recognize numbered lists
set formatoptions+=2                  " Use indent from 2nd line of a paragraph
set formatoptions+=l                  " Don't break lines that are already long
set formatoptions+=1                  " Break before 1-letter words
" Vim 7.4 only: no // comment when joining commented lines
if v:version >= 704 | set formatoptions+=j | endif
" }}}
" Syntax highlighting {{{
" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
syntax on
" }}}
" Omnicomplete settings {{{
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
set completeopt=longest,menuone
" }}}
" Text wrapping and tab widths {{{
set wrap
set textwidth=80
" highlight just the 81st column of wide lines... (Damien Conway)
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=magenta
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)

" tabwidth
set tabstop=4       " visual spaces per tab
set softtabstop=4   " spaces when editing
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
" }}}
" Autowrite settings {{{
" Write the old file out when switching between files.
set autowrite
" Saves file when Vim window loses focus
au FocusLost * :wa
" Save file with sudo powers
cmap w!! w !sudo tee %
" }}}
" Jump to last cursor position {{{
augroup vimrcEx
    au!

    " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
    " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
    " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
    autocmd BufReadPost *
                \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
                \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
                \ endif
augroup END
" }}}
" Search settings {{{
set ignorecase  " case insensitive search
set smartcase   " only case sensitive when typing capitals
set incsearch   " do incremental searching
set hlsearch    " highlight search matches
" }}}
" Folding settings {{{
" Enable code folding
set foldenable
" Use space to toggle folds and create folds
nnoremap <silent> <Space> @=(foldlevel('.')?'za':"\<Space>")<CR>
vnoremap <Space> zf
" Set foldmethod to indent and allow manual
augroup vimrc
    au BufReadPre * setlocal foldmethod=indent
    au BufWinEnter * if &fdm == 'indent' | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
augroup END
set foldlevelstart=10   " Open most folds by default
set foldnestmax=10      " 10 nested folds max
" }}}
" Git settings {{{
" Ignore whitespaces with git diffs
set diffopt+=iwhite
" }}}
" Plug plugins {{{
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'shawncplus/phpcomplete.vim', { 'for': 'php' }
Plug 'StanAngeloff/php.vim', { 'for': 'php' }
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'joonty/vdebug', { 'for': 'php' }
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'skammer/vim-css-color', { 'for': 'css' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-git'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript', { 'for': 'javascript' }
Plug 'heavenshell/vim-jsdoc', { 'for': 'javascript' }
Plug 'leshill/vim-json', { 'for': 'json' }
Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plug 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex', { 'for': 'latex' }
Plug 'kshenoy/vim-signature'
Plug 'ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace'
Plug 'Chiel92/vim-autoformat'
Plug 'hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent', { 'for': 'python' }
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'ivalkeen/vim-ctrlp-tjump'
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py --tern-completer' }
" }}}
" Vim airline {{{
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline_enable_branch     = 1
set laststatus=2
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
" }}}
" YouCompleteMe {{{
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-TAB>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-S-TAB>', '<Up>']
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '/usr/bin/python'
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-Tab>'
" }}}
" CtrlP {{{
set updatetime=250
let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
let g:ctrlp_reuse_window = 1            " Use same window
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>b :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :CtrlPTag<CR>
" CtrlP tjump
nnoremap <c-]> :CtrlPtjump<cr>
vnoremap <c-]> :CtrlPtjumpVisual<cr>
" Ignore settings
set wildignore+=*/vendor/**
"}}}
" The Silver Searcher {{{
" Use ag over grep
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

" Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects
" .gitignore
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

" ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0

" define :Ag
if !exists(":Ag")
    command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
endif

" bind K to grep word under cursor
nnoremap K :silent! grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>

" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
" }}}
" GitGutter {{{
let g:gitgutter_grep_command = 'ag --nocolor'
" }}}
" Syntastic {{{
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_loc_list_height = 5
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 1
let g:syntastic_id_checkers = 1
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = '/usr/bin/python3'
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['python', 'pylint']
let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 1

let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '?'
let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = '??'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = '??'
let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = '?'

highlight link SyntasticErrorSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticWarningSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticStyleErrorSign SignColumn
highlight link SyntasticStyleWarningSign SignColumn
" }}}
" Tagbar {{{
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>s :TagbarToggle<CR>
" }}}
" PHP settings {{{
" PHP Docblocks
function! PhpSyntaxOverride()
    hi! def link phpDocTags  phpDefine
    hi! def link phpDocParam phpType
endfunction
augroup phpSyntaxOverride
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType php call PhpSyntaxOverride()
augroup END

let g:formatdef_phpfmt = '"php ~/bin/phpfmt --no-backup --psr --smart_linebreak_after_curly --visibility_order -"'
let g:formatters_php = ['phpfmt']
" }}}
" XDebug with vdebug {{{
" TODO: per project setting of path mapping?
let g:vdebug_options = {
            \   'path_maps': {
            \       "/vagrant/dev_src/": "/home/ruben/Code/studentsplus/dev_src/",
            \   },
            \   'timeout': 30,
            \   'break_on_open': 1
            \}
"}}}
" CSS settings {{{
let g:cssColorVimDoNotMessMyUpdatetime = 1
" }}}
" LaTeX Settings {{{
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'arara -v $*'
" }}}
" Clipboard shortcuts {{{
nnoremap <C-y> "+y
vnoremap <C-y> "+y
" }}}
" UI settings {{{
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set number      " show linenumbers
set linespace=3 " Prefer a slightly higher line height
set mousehide   " Hide mouse when typing
set cursorline  " Highlight current line
set wildmenu    " visual autocomplete for command menu
set showmatch   " highlight matching [{(
" }}}
" Theme {{{
" Set the color scheme.
set background=dark
" }}}
" Vim signature (marks) {{{
let g:SignatureMarkTextHLDynamic = 1
let g:SignatureMarkerTextHLDynamic = 1
" }}}
" End Plug {{{
" Add plugins to &runtimepath
call plug#end()
" }}}
" Identation settings {{{
" Enable file type detection
" Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
" 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
" Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
filetype plugin indent on

set autoindent                        " indent when creating newline

" for autoindent, use same spaces/tabs mix as previous line, even if
" tabs/spaces are mixed. Helps for docblock, where the block comments have a
" space after the indent to align asterisks
set copyindent

" Try not to change the indent structure on "<<" and ">>" commands. I.e. keep
" block comments aligned with space if there is a space there.
set preserveindent

" Smart detect when in braces and parens. Has annoying side effect that it
" won't indent lines beginning with '#'. Relying on syntax indentexpr instead.
set nosmartindent

" Global setting. I don't edit C-style code all the time so don't default to
" C-style indenting.
set nocindent
" }}}
```

Comment: I've never used the plugin but the readme page says `Start Vdebug with <F5>, which will make it wait for an incoming connection. Run the script you want to debug, with the debugging engine enabled. A new tab will open with the debugging interface.` you didn't mention starting the script you want to debug in your post so just to be sure: do you start the script to start the debugging? Also (probably) not related to your problem but you should keep only your plugin installation/customization between `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')` and `call plug#end()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the begin/end tags. Just to be clear: I have opened a `.php` file in vim, and on a non-blank line in this file, I press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Then nothing happens. It should start a Vdebug session. I have also started the script with Xdebug enabled, but still nothing happens.

Comment: I started my vim with your `.vimrc`, installed your plugins excepted youCompleteMe which poped an error, edited a php file and pressed F5 and I got the message `Waiting for connection (Ctrl-C to cancel etc...)`. So I would be surprised but maybe youCompleteMe creates a conflict and you should try after disabling it otherwise as I can't reproduce your problem I don't know how to help you :-/ good luck :-)

Comment: I have tried that as per your suggestion, but it does not work... Very strange. Which terminal emulator are you using? Maybe something is wrong with the keycode it receives. I am using xfce4-terminal. thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Indeed good think to check I'm using rxvt-unicode on a Debian Jessie with gnome3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my `vim-gtk` was not compiled with Python support, the output of

`:echo has("python")`

Returned `0`. Manually compiling vim with python support as listed [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) solved the issue.